# Drive REST API - jquery multipart file upload

Tags: jquery, google-drive-api, multipart

I need to upload a file from browser to my Google Drive. This is my upload code: (`files` is an array of files get from `<input type="file">`)

```
      var boundary = "foo_bar_baz";
      const delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
      const close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";

      var contentType = doc.mimeType;
      var metadata = {
        "title": doc.name,
        "mimeType": doc.mimeType
      };

      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function(e){

        var multipartRequestBody =
          delimiter +  'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
          JSON.stringify(metadata) +
          delimiter + 'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' + '\r\n' +
          e.target.result +
          close_delim;

        $.ajax({
          url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=multipart',
          type: 'POST',
          headers: {
            "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + luminDriveAccessToken,
            "Content-Type": 'multipart/related; boundary="'+ boundary + '"'
          },
          success: function() {
            console.log('>>> Done uploading.');
          },
          error: _handleUploadErrors,
          data: multipartRequestBody,
          cache: false,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          crossDomain: true
        });
      };

      reader.readAsBinaryString(files[0]);
```

When I run this script, the file got uploaded to my Google Drive (correct title, correct mimeType) but the file content is broken (Google Drive can't open it). When I download the file to my computer, I can't open it either and **I realize that the downloaded file's size is slighly bigger than the original one** *(for example of a .docx file: 15.4KB in comparison with 11.3KB).*
So I guess the problem is related to the file content before sending it to the server. But I don't know how to fix it yet. Hope you guys could help !

Comment: have you tried submitting using FormData API?

Comment: I haven't (In fact I don't know how to). I just follow the API here: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/manage-uploads

Answer (score 0):

I find out the solution by converting reader's result to base64Data then add **Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64** to the body of the request.

```
reader.onload = function(e){
        var base64Data = btoa(e.target.result);
        var multipartRequestBody =
          delimiter +  'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
          JSON.stringify(metadata) +
          delimiter + 'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' +
          'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' + '\r\n' +
          base64Data + close_delim;

        $.ajax({
          url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=multipart',
          type: 'POST',
          headers: {
            "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + ACCESS_TOKEN,
            "Content-Type": 'multipart/related; boundary="'+ boundary + '"'
          },
          success: function() {
            // TODO XIN
            console.log('>>> DONE');
          },
          error: _handleUploadErrors,
          data: multipartRequestBody,
          cache: false,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          crossDomain: true
        });
      };
```